# Selected value is not showing for dropdownlist in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Model

```
public class LeadsVM
{
    public LeadsVM()
    {
        this.leadsList = new List<SingleLeadVM>();
    }

    public IList<SingleLeadVM> leadsList { get; set; }

    // For backup user and assign user 
    public IEnumerable<UserProfile> users { get; set; }

    public LeadDetailsVM leadDetailsVM { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Lead status")]
    public IEnumerable<LeadStatus> leadStatusList { get; set; }

}
```

View

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.leadsList.Count; i++)
{    
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].assignedToUserId, new SelectList(Model.users, "UserId", "Email"), "Select user", new { data_val = false, data_users = Model.leadsList[i].leadId, @class = "usersList" })
}
```

The reason why I am using for loop rather than foreach is that I can submit collection of data back to controller. The problem is that even if the value can be passed from View to controller and vice versa I am unable to display correct value in dropdown list(I can always see optional label).

Solution

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].assignedToUserId, new SelectList(Model.users, "UserId", "Email", Model.leadsList[i].assignedToUserId), "Select user", new { data_val = false, data_users = Model.leadsList[i].leadId, @class = "usersList" })
```

Comment: If you think you found the solution, you can answer your own question and mark it as answer.

Comment: Also instead of an `IEnumerable` make leadStatusList a `List<SelectListItem>`, that will make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Turned out that I could use the 4th parameter of the SelectList constructor.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.leadsList[i].assignedToUserId, 
new SelectList(Model.users, "UserId", "Email", Model.leadsList[i].assignedToUserId),
"Select user", 
new { data_val = false, data_users = Model.leadsList[i].leadId, @class = "usersList" })
```